# How to lock innerBlocks within a block variation?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to create a new group block that includes one `core/heading` block and then one `core/gallery` block. I do not want editors to be able to add other inner blocks to the group. Nor do I want editors to be able to delete either of the heading or gallery blocks.

Here is my block variation so far:

```js
    wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation("core/group", {
        name: "logo-grid",
        title: "Logo Grid",
        description: "",
        category: "media",
        icon: "smiley",
        scope: ["inserter"],
        attributes: {
        },
        innerBlocks: [
            ["core/heading", { level: 2, placeholder: "Heading" }],
            ["core/gallery"],
        ],
    });
```

I've looked into `templateLock` and `template_lock` and `lock` attributes but none seem to apply to block variations?

I realize I may be using the wrong tool for the job by trying to create a block variation with this functionality. Any advice for how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this has changed since the original post, but I am able to add template locking to a block variation as follows in WordPress 6.2.2 by adjusting the `attributes` of the block variation.

For locking removal and movement:

```js
    wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation("core/group", {
        name: "logo-grid-lock",
        title: "Logo Grid Locked",
        description: "",
        category: "media",
        icon: "smiley",
        scope: ["inserter"],
        attributes: {
            lock: {
                move: 'true',
                remove: 'true',
            }
        },
        innerBlocks: [
            ["core/heading", { level: 2, placeholder: "Heading" }],
            ["core/gallery"],
        ],
    });
```

Using the even more restrictive content-editing-only "template lock":

```js
    wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation("core/group", {
        name: "logo-grid-templatel-locked",
        title: "Logo Grid Template Locked",
        description: "",
        category: "media",
        icon: "smiley",
        scope: ["inserter"],
        attributes: {
            templateLock: 'contentOnly'
        },
        innerBlocks: [
            ["core/heading", { level: 2, placeholder: "Heading" }],
            ["core/gallery"],
        ],
    });
```

[Locking Blocks in WordPress 5.9](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/08/locking-blocks-in-wordpress-5-9/)
[Content only editing and other locking updates](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/11/content-locking-features-and-updates/)

Comment: I attempted adding templateLock: 'all' and templateLock: 'contentOnly' as shown in this example, and it did not work for me. I am still able to delete and move the InnerBlocks. I don't want to lock the block itself, only the innerblocks. Anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this out. Instead of creating a block variation, I just created a brand new block using a block template.

```js
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const BLOCKS_TEMPLATE = [
    ["core/heading", { level: 2, placeholder: "Heading" }],
    ["core/gallery", {}],
];

registerBlockType("logo-grid", {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: "Logo Grid",
    icon: "smiley",
    category: "media",
    edit: () => {
        return (
            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <InnerBlocks
                    orientation="horizontal"
                    template={BLOCKS_TEMPLATE}
                    templateLock="all"
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>                
                <InnerBlocks.Content />               
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: Note: Since this answer was posted, there is a [newer and more flexible way to work with InnerBlocks](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/12/28/take-more-control-over-inner-block-areas-as-a-block-developer/) that doesn't use the InnerBlocks component.